# Converting string array characters to numbers

Tags: c, string, char, character

I am new to C. I am experienced in GWBASIC. In an effort to learn, I am attempting to write a program that will convert the individual chars in a string to a numerical value as so:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
a b c d e f g h i
j k l m n o p q r
s t u v w x y z
```

For example, user input for string A could be 'dog',
said program would then store [d][o][g] as [4][6][7] in string B.
The below code works for a string w/up to four chars, but there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

```
int main()
{
    char a[0];
    char b[0];
    scanf("%s",a);
    if (a[0] == 'a' || a[0] == 'j' || a[0] == 's') b[0] = '1';
    if (a[0] == 'b' || a[0] == 'k' || a[0] == 't') b[0] = '2';
    if (a[0] == 'c' || a[0] == 'l' || a[0] == 'u') b[0] = '3';
    if (a[0] == 'd' || a[0] == 'm' || a[0] == 'v') b[0] = '4';
    if (a[0] == 'e' || a[0] == 'n' || a[0] == 'w') b[0] = '5';
    if (a[0] == 'f' || a[0] == 'o' || a[0] == 'x') b[0] = '6';
    if (a[0] == 'g' || a[0] == 'p' || a[0] == 'y') b[0] = '7';
    if (a[0] == 'h' || a[0] == 'q' || a[0] == 'z') b[0] = '8';
    if (a[0] == 'i' || a[0] == 'r') b[0] = '9';
    if (a[1] == 'a' || a[1] == 'j' || a[1] == 's') b[1] = '1'; 
    if (a[1] == 'b' || a[1] == 'k' || a[1] == 't') b[1] = '2';
    if (a[1] == 'c' || a[1] == 'l' || a[1] == 'u') b[1] = '3';
    if (a[1] == 'd' || a[1] == 'm' || a[1] == 'v') b[1] = '4';
    if (a[1] == 'e' || a[1] == 'n' || a[1] == 'w') b[1] = '5';
    if (a[1] == 'f' || a[1] == 'o' || a[1] == 'x') b[1] = '6';
    if (a[1] == 'g' || a[1] == 'p' || a[1] == 'y') b[1] = '7';
    if (a[1] == 'h' || a[1] == 'q' || a[1] == 'z') b[1] = '8';
    if (a[1] == 'i' || a[1] == 'r') b[1] = '9';
    if (a[2] == 'a' || a[2] == 'j' || a[2] == 's') b[2] = '1';
    if (a[2] == 'b' || a[2] == 'k' || a[2] == 't') b[2] = '2';
    if (a[2] == 'c' || a[2] == 'l' || a[2] == 'u') b[2] = '3';
    if (a[2] == 'd' || a[2] == 'm' || a[2] == 'v') b[2] = '4';
    if (a[2] == 'e' || a[2] == 'n' || a[2] == 'w') b[2] = '5';
    if (a[2] == 'f' || a[2] == 'o' || a[2] == 'x') b[2] = '6';
    if (a[2] == 'g' || a[2] == 'p' || a[2] == 'y') b[2] = '7';
    if (a[2] == 'h' || a[2] == 'q' || a[2] == 'z') b[2] = '8';
    if (a[2] == 'i' || a[2] == 'r') b[2] = '9';
    if (a[3] == 'a' || a[3] == 'j' || a[3] == 's') b[3] = '1';
    if (a[3] == 'b' || a[3] == 'k' || a[3] == 't') b[3] = '2';
    if (a[3] == 'c' || a[3] == 'l' || a[3] == 'u') b[3] = '3';
    if (a[3] == 'd' || a[3] == 'm' || a[3] == 'v') b[3] = '4';
    if (a[3] == 'e' || a[3] == 'n' || a[3] == 'w') b[3] = '5';
    if (a[3] == 'f' || a[3] == 'o' || a[3] == 'x') b[3] = '6';
    if (a[3] == 'g' || a[3] == 'p' || a[3] == 'y') b[3] = '7';
    if (a[3] == 'h' || a[3] == 'q' || a[3] == 'z') b[3] = '8';
    if (a[3] == 'i' || a[3] == 'r') b[3] = '9';
    printf("%s\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note that in C the '=' operator is assignment, to check equality use the == operator. You could something like if(strA[0] == 'a' || strA[0] == 'j' || strA[0] == 's') strB[0] = 1; ... and so on for the other cases, to check this for every character use a for or while loop and instead of the 0 use an incremented value.

Comment: @rankep: I think that salicemspiritus wants `strB[0] = '1'` rather than `strB[0] = 1`.

Comment: Also, to check if a value is equal to a character, you have to put the character within apostropges: `if (strA[0] == 'a')`

Comment: There's no such thing as an array of 0 length; you need `char a[1]`.

Comment: @ruakh yes you are absolutely right, this happens when I'm in a hurry, and just try to leave a quick comment.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your compiler uses an ASCII encoding then you can use the following simple arithmetic to get your answer:

```
1 + (strA[i] - 'a') % 9
```

You really don't want to implement this with a long list of `if` statements or indeed a `switch` statement.

Naturally you will have input validation issues if you have non alphabetical characters, numeric characters, upper-case characters and so on. I presume you can simply ignore those for a learning exercise.

Comment: Just a side note: Based on the chart provided, I believe the OP would then have to `%9` this value.

Comment: @williamg my guess is that chart needs to be corrected!!   ;-)

Comment: I would have thought so too, but in his comment he used the columns 1-9 regardless of the row. However, I have a bad habit of assuming things... ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: seeing how 'o' gets converted to '6', I think the OP means to use only 1-9.

Comment: Thank you, but I am unsure of how to apply this.

Answer (score 2):

To correct your original approach, you need to do two things:

- Use single quotes around character constants;
- Use `==` to check for equality;
- Terminate statements with `;`.

... so your snippet becomes:

```
if (strA[0] == 'a')
    strB[0] = '1';
if (strA[0] == 'b')
    strB[0] = '2';
if (strA[0] == 'c')
    strB[0] = '3';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can type the following exactly into a gwbasic editor and it will solve your problem

```
10 INPUT A$

12 L = LEN(A$)

15 FOR T = 1 TO L

20 M$ = MID$(A$,T,1)

25 GOSUB 70

30 B$ = B$ + V$

35 NEXT T

40 PRINT B$

50 END

55 REM -----------------

70 REM - Subroutine to convert m$ into v$

72 X = ASC(M$) : REM this is the ascii value of m$ (eg. "a" = 97)

74 X = X - 96 : REM so that 97 becomes "1"

80 IF X > 9 THEN X = X - 9 : GOTO 80

90 V$ = STR$(X) : REM just converting to a string type variable

95 RETURN : REM takes you back to line 30 where this value is added to the

96 REM final resulting B$ - when I say added I mean a char added to a string

97 REM such that   "APPL" + "E" = "APPLE"

98 REM ------------------------------------------ DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

For ASCII, it would go somewhat like:

```
... make sure strB has enough space ...
for (i = 0; i < ... length of strA ... ; i++) {
    /* you should always check your input is valid */
    if (strA[i] >= 'a' && strB[i] <= 'z')
        strB[i] = (strA[i] - 'a') % 9 + 1;
    else
        strB[i] = ... some default value ...
}
```

For EBCDIC:

```
for (i = 0; i < ... length of strA ... ; i++) {
    /* you should always check your input is valid */
    if (strA[i] >= 'a' && strB[i] <= 'r')
        strB[i] = strA[i] & 0xF;
    else if (strA[i] >= 's' && strB <= 'z')
        strB[i] = (strA[i] & 0xF) - 1;
    else
        strB[i] = ... some default value ...
}
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: heh, nice and EBCDIC in the same sentence, who would have thought?

Comment: @salice yes you do. But that's very basic C and unrelated to the question you asked.

Comment: @David Thank you for all your help. I am still unable to apply what you have said. I apologize for being a novice, I am doing my best to learn.

Comment: Try to use the suggestions that ninjalj and I have made. The key is to use `1 + (strA[i] - 'a') % 9` instead of your if statements. Write a complete program that way and then if that does not work ask a new question containing that complete program. Then we can help. But do not persist in writing it out in `if` statements and do not use copy/paste as a primary development tool.

Comment: This will be my goal tonight. Thank you very much for your help; you are a good person.

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at an ASCII table. You'll see that all letters are encoded with some integer value. As a start, if you only have lower case letters, it's enough to substract the character code of 'a' from any letter to get what you want

```
int nr = strA[0] - 'a' + 1;
//now you'd need to convert back to a string; better: strB should be an array of integer
```

Also, `=` is the assignment operator; you need to use `==` to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
int strB[MAX_LEN] = {0};
char *strA = malloc (MAX_LEN * sizeof(char));
int i,c = 0,x;

scanf("%s",strA);

for(i = 0 ; i<strlen(strA) ; i++){
    x = strA[i] - 'a' + 1;
    if(x >= 1 && x <= 9)
        strB[c] = x;
    else if(x <= 18){
        strB[c] = x - 10;
    else if(x <= 26){
        strB[c] = x - 19;
    if(x <= 26)
        c++;
}
```

or you can use ninjalj approach in the for loop, if you aleady checked the input:

```
for(i=0 ; i<strlen(strA) ; i++){
    strB[i] = (strA[i] - 'a') % 9 + 1;
}
```

or this :

```
for(i=0 ; i<strlen(strA) ; i++){
    if(strA[i] >= 'a' && strA[i] <= 'z'){
        strB[c] = (strA[i] - 'a') % 9 + 1;
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you dynamically allocating `strA`, if `strB` is statically allocated?